# How to create a dropdown from a gtk.Entry's icon?

Tags: pygtk

I have a gtk.Entry with an icon after the text, intending to be a text search field:

[image: gtk.Entry for search]

What I'm trying to do is to display a dropdown (i.e. a gtk.ComboBox) when the user clicks on the icon, to choose the type of search.  A mock of that feature would be:

[image: Mock of gtk.Entry with icon ComboBox]

I have tried several things without any success.  For example, trying to pack an empty gtk.ComboBox only showing an arrow right after the Entry, and stuffing it only on icon-press, which creates the illusion, but it has two drawbacks: a) when I stuff the ComboBox, the toolbar grows, and b) when I clear() the ListStore, the ComboBox retains its width and leaves an ugly grey box.

At this point I guess that I need to create a CellRenderer on icon-press that pops down the icon of the Entry, and I tried without a lot of success to understand the code of gtk.ComboBoxEntry (in [gtkcomboboxentry.c](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkcomboboxentry.c?h=gtk-2-24)), but as far as I understood it uses a vertical Container on the whole piece together with a CellRenderer.

Also GTK+3 doesn't have any ideas on this respect.

Any ideas, or some guidance in how to create this in PyGTK?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "GTK+3 doesn't have any ideas at this respect" but what you described can be done with a Gtk.Popover (Gtk+ >= 3.12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for something similar, so I came up with the code below. I haven't really worried about the aesthetics. I did pass a list of tuples to the MyPopup class, with the idea of passing handlers for each of the menu items in the dropdown. Note that the `item.show()` is necessary, even though there is a `show_all()`:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyPopup(Gtk.MenuButton):
    def __init__(self, btndefs):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__()

        self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
        self.set_popup(self.menu)
        #self.set_label(">")
        self.set_direction(Gtk.ArrowType.RIGHT)

        for btndef in btndefs:
            item = Gtk.MenuItem()
            item.set_label(btndef[0])
            item.show()
            self.menu.append(item)

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.set_size_request(100, -1)
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()

        self.popup = MyPopup( (("String",),
                               ("String no case",),
                               ("Hexadecimal",),
                               ("Regexp",)) )

        self.hbox.pack_start(self.entry, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.popup, False, True, 0)

        self.add(self.hbox)

        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main():
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

yup its year late, but lets not make next person stumbled here to be **sad** like me.

this is the example using **Gtk.Menu()** *popup*, you can also similar feat. with **Gtk.Popover()**

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

opts = {
    'hex'     : "system-run-symbolic",
    'regex'   : "font-select-symbolic",
    'string'  : "font-x-generic-symbolic",
    'no-case' : "tools-check-spelling-symbolic",
}

def make_menu(entry, opts):
    menu = Gtk.Menu()
    for label, icon in opts.items():
        item = Gtk.MenuItem()
        item.set_label(label)
        item.connect(
            "activate",
            lambda w: entry.set_icon_from_icon_name(0, opts[w.get_label()])
        )
        menu.append(item)

        # NOTE you can use Gtk.ImageMenuItem to add image but its
        # Deprecated since version 3.10

    menu.show_all()
    return menu


def on_icon_release(widget, pos, event):
    menu = make_menu(widget, opts)
    menu.popup(
        parent_menu_shell = None,
        parent_menu_item  = None,
        func              = None,
        data              = None,
        button            = Gdk.BUTTON_PRIMARY,
        activate_time     = event.get_time()
    )

def make_entry():
    entry = Gtk.Entry()
    entry.set_icon_from_icon_name(0, 'action-unavailable-symbolic')
    entry.set_icon_from_icon_name(1, 'fonts')
    entry.set_icon_sensitive(1, True)
    entry.set_icon_activatable(1, True)
    entry.connect("icon-release", on_icon_release)
    return entry


root = Gtk.Window()
root.add(make_entry())
root.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```